# more and less text toggle on a data retrieved through jquery ajax response from another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I m creating a small functionality of toggling more and less text in jquery on a data which is retrived one at a time and appended to div container from getData page when clicked on button using ajax... The problem is when first time the button is clicked data is retrieved the more and less text functionality is working fine but when the button is clicked second time and the data is retrived second time and appended to div then show more and less text works on currently retrieved data but not on previously all retrieved data ... someone please help me regarding this ... Thanks

**recordsDisplay.html**

```
<div id="container">
</div>
<button id="click">Click Me</button>
```

**style.css :**

```
a.morelink {
    color:red;
}
.morecontent span {
    display: none;

}
```

**jquery :**

```
var showChar = 150;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
$('#click').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "getData.html",
        method : "GET",
        success : function(response){
            $('#container').append(response);
            var mymore = $('#container').find('.more');
$(mymore).each(function() {

                var content = $(this).html();
                if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

                $(this).html(html);

                }

            });
            $(".morelink").click(function(){

        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
}
        })
```

**getData.html:**

```
<h5 class="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed faucibus, ligula ornare viverra sodales, magna erat semper ante, non placerat nulla lorem id orci. Praesent auctor ultrices sodales. Etiam vitae eros nisi. Morbi dictum, turpis at varius ornare, ante diam dignissim erat, a vulputate eros massa sit amet quam. Donec viverra pharetra odio, nec porta libero sagittis ac. Nam porta ornare feugiat. Maecenas </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var showChar = 150;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
      $('#click').click(function(){
       $.ajax({
          url : "getData.html",
          method : "GET",
          success : function(response){
            $('#container').append(response);
            var mymore = $('#container').find('.more');
            $(mymore).each(function() {
              var content = $(this).html();
              console.log(content);
              console.log(content.indexOf(ellipsestext) );
              if(content.length > showChar) {
                if (content.indexOf(ellipsestext) < 0){
                  var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                  var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
                  var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';
                  $(this).html(html);
                }
              }
            });

          }
        });
      });
      $('body').on("click",".morelink",function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
          $(this).removeClass("less");
          $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
          $(this).addClass("less");
          $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
      });
```

You missed a condition after every time get new data, because already appended html having the format of more or less so if you again edit this then it will lost the more data. so i added a condition not to edit old data again

its just on condition

```
if (content.indexOf(ellipsestext) < 0){
```

and also you don't need to put 
$('.morelink').click() function inside ajax call it will make one even multiple time, so better is load it outside the event as i give and bind it to body , so it will work on dynamic element also

```
$('body').on("click",".morelink",function(){
```